# How to have an object's pk as an integer?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```py
class Class(models.Model):
    class_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.class_id = self.pk+1000
        super(Class, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, I want `pk` to be added to 1000 and use that as `class_id` value. But I get this error:

```
TypeError at /new-class

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

How can I have the pk as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the id is None before you have saved the instance to the database.

In any case, why store this value to the database if it's always id + 1000? You could use a property instead. I would recommend this solution because it does not require any changes to the database, and is easy to refactor later if the requirements change.

```
class Class(models.Model):

    @property
    def class_id(self):
        return self.pk and self.pk + 1000
```

An alternative to using a property is queryset [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

```
from django.db.models import F
qs = Class.objects.annotate(class_id=F('pk') + 1000)
qs.get(id=42).class_id  # model instance attribute with value 1042
```

If you want to use your original approach, you must modify the save method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding:
        # save once to get a id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.class_id = self.pk + 1000
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It occurs to me that you *might* be able to use an F-expression (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to get the DB to calculate the value for self.class_id. It will depend whether it initializes pk before trying to evaluate class_id.

Comment: @nigel222: There's all sorts of hacks and workaround that are _possible_. But working against the tools (the Django ORM) often leads to more bugs and unmaintainable and hard to understand code. There's almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

pk *is* an integer, but it does not get set until after the model is created since it comes from a sequence in the database.

You can also use the boolean self._state.adding to determine whether or not the model has already been created.